# Error in setting user roles in php using access column in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have a login/register website. both admin and users are in the same table in mysql.

My users table is below:

[image]

There is certain pages where only admins can visit. I have made an access column and put the values like in the image. I have the following php code for checking whether its admin or not

```html
<?
  include("config.php");

session_start();
$user_email=$_SESSION['email'];
  $check_user="select * from users WHERE user_email='$user_email'";

  $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);

while($row = $run->fetch_assoc())
{

 $user_name=$row['user_name'];


}?>
<div class="sing"><?php

  if ($_SESSION['access'] != 'admin') {
  header("Location: login.php");
  }


else if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] == true) {
  echo " &nbsp You logged in as " . $_SESSION['email'] ;
echo "<div style='float: right;'><a href='logout.php'>logout</a>&nbsp</div>";
}
else{}
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
  <title>Nurses Pulse </title>
  <!--/tags -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="application/x-javascript">
   addEventListener("load", function () {
    setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
   }, false);

   function hideURLbar() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
   }
  </script>
  <!--//tags -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/imageedit_2_5125240109.gif"/>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="css/appointment_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- //for bootstrap working -->
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
  <!-- header -->
  <div class="header" id="home">

   <div class="content white">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
        <h1 style="color:#e50000"><span class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></span>Nurses Pulse </h1>
       </a>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-header-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <nav>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>


         <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Exams <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="prometric.php">PROMETRIC</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           <li><a href="haadexam.php">HAAD</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           <li><a href="moh.php">MOH</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>

          </ul>
         </li>

                 <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>


        </ul>
       </nav>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
      <!--/.navbar-->
     </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- banner -->
  <!--//banner -->
  <!-- about -->

 <!-- emergency -->
 <!-- //emergency -->
 <!-- services -->
 <div class="services">
 <div class="container">
   <h3 class="heading-agileinfo" style="color:#e50000"><span>Sorry! You Have Timed Out!</span></h3>

   <div class="services-top-grids">
       <div> </div><br>
 <br>
   <?php

   $session_value=(isset($_SESSION['correct_score']))?$_SESSION['correct_score']:'';
   $session_value2=(isset($_SESSION['not_correct_score']))?$_SESSION['not_correct_score']:'';
   echo "<div class='div-left'> Number Of Correct Answers = " . $session_value . "</div>";
   echo "<div class='div-left'> <br>Number Of Wrong Answers = " . $session_value2 . "</div>";
    ?>

   </div>
   <div class="services-bottom-grids">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- //services -->
 <!-- Clients -->

 <!-- //Clients -->
 <!--/icons-->
  <!--//icons-->

  <!-- footer -->
  <div class="footer_top_agile_w3ls">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 footer_grid">
     <h3>About Us</h3>
     <p>NursesPulse is for those who are preparing for the staff nurse entrance exam for abroad.

     </p>


           </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 footer_grid">
            <h3>Other Services</h3>
            <ul class="footer_grid_list">
             <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <a href="exambooking.php" >Book Exam </a>
             </li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <a href="#">Course Materials</a>
             </li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <a href="membership.php" >Membership </a>
             </li>
      <!-- <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Nurses Pulse Demo.</a>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Nurses Pulse Demo. </a>
      </li> -->
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 footer_grid">
     <h3>Contact Info</h3>
     <ul class="address">
      <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>Team Pulse, Kannur <span>Kerala.</span></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="mailto:nursespulse.com">nursespulse@gmail.com</a></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>+91 95444 12311</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 footer_grid ">
     <h3>Sign up for our Newsletter</h3>
     <p>Get Started For Free</p>
     <div class="footer_grid_right">

      <form action="#" method="post">
       <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address..." required="">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer_wthree_agile">
   <p>© 2018 Nurses Pulse. All rights reserved | Design by <a href="">Bluroe Labs</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- //footer -->
  <!-- bootstrap-modal-pop-up -->
  <div class="modal video-modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      Nurses Pulse
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img src="images/g7.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
       <p></i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <!-- //bootstrap-modal-pop-up -->

  <!-- js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $('ul.dropdown-menu li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
   }, function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
   });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

The code is not working, it's redirecting me to login page even if its admin who logs in.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have `start_session()`  in your page...!

Comment: yes. at the top

Comment: share your full code for better understand...!

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: where is you set `$_SESSION['access']` in your code ..?

Comment: admin                  ...................

Comment: but you dont define in code so you can define its on code

Comment: can you explain as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
while($row = $run->fetch_assoc())
{

 $user_name=$row['user_name'];
 $_SESSION['access'] = $row['access']; //define here

}?>
<div class="sing"><?php

  if ($_SESSION['access'] != 'admin') {
  header("Location: login.php");
  }
```

Comment: let me check and tell